# How to express Array<T>.class

Tags: java, collections

I have a method that needs a Object.class parameter like

```
 method(Object.class)
```

How can I set the class to an Array of this class? Something like

```
 method(ArrayList<Object>.class)
```

I tried

```
 method(new ArrayList<Object>() {})
```

as well. It doesnt work.

Comment: What about just using `method(ArrayList.class)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Object[].class`.

(`int[].class`, `String[].class`, `double[][][].class` etc also works for that matter.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way by extending your custom class from ArrayList

```
class UserList extends ArrayList<User>{}
```

Now you can do this

```
UserList.class
```